# with an input checkbox inside a table row, can i add click event to row and still be able to click input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something Else</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' value='clickme' id='yes'></td>
  </tr>
```

For the user, if they click the row, they get more data about the row, and if they click the checkbox, they are presented with some other options.  how can i listen for each event in jquery.  My problem is that the click for checkbox obviously fires off the event for the row click

```
$('tr').click(function(){
     alert('you clicked the row');
});
$('#yes').change(function(){
      alert('you clicked the checkbox');
});
```

if element is created dynamically, would this work:

```
        $('#someTableId').on('click','#yes',function(e){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Update: the answer to part 2 yes.

Comment: In your click handler for the row, check for the target property of the event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) try this:-

```
$('#yes').click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/9/)

Comment: If we have multiple rows and having one checkbox for each row with same ID then it's only working for the first row. any suggestion about this

Comment: for multiple checkbox scenarios, if I select checkboxes by class name then it's working fine

Answer (score 4):

Use [event.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop event bubbling up, you will need to bind new click event for checkbox.

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q6ysxr0x/2/)

```
$('#yes').click(function(event){         
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

One other alternative could be withing adding addition click handler for `checkbox` is to skip the processing of tr click handler when event source is `checkbox`.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q6ysxr0x/3/)

```
$('tr').click(function(event){
    if(event.target.id === 'yes') return;
     alert('you clicked the row');        
});
```

Comment: i don't think it will work. change will not stop propagation of click on `#yes`. fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5wthn3n4/

Comment: Thanks @Junaid, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropagation();

**Definition**

Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.